# Using the key, remove all keys with similar values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

My goal is to have a random name of a fruit stored as fruit_name. Using this  I would like to remove all fruits with the same first three letters in its value. For example:

```
fruit_name = 'apple II'
dictionary = {'grape' : 'abc.asrtyui', 'apple' : 'xyz7.qwertyui',  'apple I' : 'xyz.rghhyui',  'grape II' : 'zxs2.qwertyui',  'apple II' : 'xyz.qwvnyyui', 'orange' : 'bnm1.qrthnrui'}
```

My thought process is: **STEP 1:** find the key with fruit_name (in this case 'apple II') **STEP 2:** look at first three letters for its value **STEP 3:** remove the all the keys and its values with those same three letters.
So for my example above, after this process happens the dictionary would contain:

```
dictionary = {'grape' : 'abc.asrtyui', 'grape II' : 'zxs2.qwertyui', 'orange' : 'bnm1.qrthnrui'}
```

Here is my snippet, not sure if I am going in the right direction as I am completely confused. **ALSO**, id like to do this with the standard library. Thanks in advance!

```
for k1, v1 in dictionary.items():
    for k2, v2 in dictionary.items():
        if k1 == k2:
            continue
        if v1[:3] == v2[:3]:
```

Comment: Where do you use `fruit_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have to loop over the dictionary once.  Using a dictionary comprehension, we can express "all the keys/values where the value does not start with the first three letters of the value of key `"apple II"`"

```
fruit_name = 'apple II'
dictionary = {'grape' : 'abc.asrtyui', 'apple' : 'xyz7.qwertyui',  'apple I' : 'xyz.rghhyui',  'grape II' : 'zxs2.qwertyui',  'apple II' : 'xyz.qwvnyyui', 'orange' : 'bnm1.qrthnrui'}

{k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if not v.startswith(dictionary[fruit_name][:3])}
# {'grape': 'abc.asrtyui', 'grape II': 'zxs2.qwertyui', 'orange': 'bnm1.qrthnrui'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit_name = 'apple II'
dictionary = {'grape' : 'abc.asrtyui', 'apple' : 'xyz7.qwertyui',  'apple I' : 'xyz.rghhyui',  'grape II' : 'zxs2.qwertyui',  'apple II' : 'xyz.qwvnyyui', 'orange' : 'bnm1.qrthnrui'}
val = fruit_name[:3]
delete_vals = []
for i in dictionary.keys():
    if i[:3] == val:
        delete_vals.append(i)
for i in delete_vals:
    del dictionary[i]
```

So, what's going on here? First, we define a variable `val` as the first three letters of your `fruit_name` by using string slicing. Then, we go through the keys of the dictionary and find all of those were the first three characters of the key match `val` and append them to a "delete list" (can't delete them in the loop because then you'd be modifying what you are iterating over). Then in a separate for loop, we go through the delete list and delete the corresponding value in the dictionary.

Not necessarily the shortest way of doing it, but simplest to the eye.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    if fruit_name == dictionary[fruit_name]:
        del dictionary[fruit_name]
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: why the `while True` loop? It won't break and it will never end. Also, `fruit_name` never changes. Why would you compare the key for `fruit_name` to its value in the dictionary?

Comment: Because he wants to delete multiple items. When there are no more items to delete, exit loop because false. He did not state there was a locked number of values he wants to delete.

Comment: Yes but this will never delete any items, and will only hang forever. `fruit_name` is never equal to `dictionary[fruit_name]`, and the while loop never ends

Comment: If fruit_name is a string "apple II" and the key he wants to delete is a string "apple II" then believe me, in Python 3, the code is three lines and completely viable as an answer and makes good use of the hashing involved with the search used on dictionaries

Comment: Even if `fruit_name == dictionary[fruit_name]`, and that was what OP was asking for, how does the while loop end after the key gets deleted? What is the result you get from running this code?